# Do list() function and mysqli_fetch_array work together?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have created a php code with some help in which i fetched out all similar arrays in my mysql table using while loop... the code is`

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    global $con;


    $sql1= "SELECT name FROM vi_books ORDER BY views DESC";


    $query1= mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

   $new_row=htmlspecialchars($row['name']);

    echo "<br>";
echo $new_row;   
}
?>
```

`

Now i wanted to manipulate the result array using list function so that i can echo only some specific results. Supposedly, i want to run the following code
`list($s1,$s2)=$new_row;
echo $s1."and".$s2;`

But on running this nothing is showing(like empty values are been passed in my list function variables). Plzz help me out. I guess i need AJAX or JS to manipulate the array result as i want to. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here, depending on where you use `list()`:

1. `$new_row` is a string and not an array in your code, so using `list()` with that variable does not make any sense.
2. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), *list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0* and you are getting an associative array with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. You'd need to switch to `mysqli_fetch_array()` or use `array_values()` on the result to be able to use `list()`.

By the way, using an array is almost always more convenient than setting multiple variables.

Comment: used both(mysqli_fetch_array and array_values) functions but not solving the issue